# Doctrine symfony remove entity with OneToMany - ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

I have two entities Activities and BulleManager. I use OneToMany - ManyToOne for the relationship between them. The problem is that when i delete a row in BulleManager entity, the related row in the Activities entity is deleted too, and that is not the behaviour i like. I want just to set "NULL" to the inversed side entity(Activities) when the owning side(BulleManager) entity is deleted.

```
class Activities
{
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BulleManager", 
      cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="activities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bulle_manager_id", 
     referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
     protected $bulleManager;
...
}

class BulleManager
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Activities", 
     mappedBy="bulleManager", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $activities;
}
```

Your solution are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `cascade={"remove"}` from your BulleManager entity.

`cascade={"remove"}` deletes all dependent records in the Child Table (Activities) if a record is deleted in Parent Table (BulleManager).

Now, it will set `bullemanager_id` to `NULL` in Activities table if a BulleManager is deleted.

And, Don't forgot to update your database schema using:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```

Comment: The struggle is that when i remove the cascade={"remove"} from BulleManager, the removal doesn't have effect in the database for the BulleManager entity (The row is not deleted). **FYI** I use the method remove() of doctrine to remove the entity.

Comment: Ah it works. in fact, the problem is not from the cascade nor from the relationship but the way i code in the controller. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: No problem. Thanks